# Shiny with R: How to add data with each click to the graph?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I created a Shiny using R.
It succeeded to read the data and disapply a plot.

but now I want to upgrade it so the user will be able to insert a new term in the textbox and the graph of the new term will be added to the previous graphs on the same plot.

I wrote a code, but I get an error...

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library (rio)

data_func <- function(term)
{ 
  data<-import(paste("G:/My Drive/PhD/Trends/model_data/",term,".csv",sep=""))
  return(data)

  }

# Define UI --------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      HTML("Welcome to the predictor of trends in science"),
      actionButton("go", "Go"),
      
      
      textInput(inputId = "term",
                label = "Insert your term",
                value = "")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server ----------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  v<-reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  data <- reactiveVal(
data_frame(Year=c(),publications_count=c(),review_publications_count=c(),Term=c(),general_publication=c(),norm_publications_count=c(),norm_review_publications_count=c()
  ))
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    v$data <- rbind(v$data,data_func(input$term))
  })
  

  
  Term<-eventReactive(input$go, {input$term})
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(v$data)) return() 
    ggplot(data = data(), aes(x = Year, y = norm_publications_count, color = Term())) +
      geom_point()

  })
}
 

# Create a Shiny app object ----------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Warning: Error in geom_point: Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'Year' not found
  195: <Anonymous>
  194: signalCondition
  193: signal_abort
  192: rlang::abort
  191: cli::cli_abort
  190: handlers[[1L]]
  189: h
  188: .handleSimpleError
  187: FUN
  186: lapply
  185: scales_add_defaults
  184: compute_aesthetics
  183: l$compute_aesthetics
  182: f
  175: by_layer
  174: ggplot_build.ggplot
  172: print.ggplot
  167: func
  165: f
  164: Reduce
  155: do
  154: hybrid_chain
  126: drawPlot
  112: <reactive:plotObj>
   96: drawReactive
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$scatterplot
    1: runApp
Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.
```

I will really appreciate your help!
Thanks!
Hadasa

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please share a minimal reproducible example by including data, e.g. by using `dput()`. Also please clarify what you mean by "term", i.e., an example what the input should be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add rows to R Shiny table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72048396/how-to-add-rows-to-r-shiny-table)